# Cypress - iterating through same elements with different values?

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-testing

I have this DOM:

```
div<data-hook='cart-content'>
    <section data-hook="item">  
        <h3 data-hook='product-name'>Winter Feel Package</h3>
    <section data-hook="item">  
        <h3 data-hook='product-name'>Christmas Wreath</h3>
```

I want to verify that my item name exist in the DOM (one time I will test it using the first value "Winter Feel Package" and then with "Christmas Wreath") however when I use the naive approch of 'cy.get' I am getting the only first item.

this is what I tried:
first I tried the naive approach:

```
getProductName(itemName){
        cy.get("iframe[title='Cart Page']").its('0.contentDocument')
        .should('exist').its('body')
        .should('not.be.undefined').then(cy.wrap)
        .find("div[data-hook='item-list'] section[data-hook='item'] h3[data-hook='product-name']")
        .then(($elem)=>{
            expect($elem).to.have.text(itemName)
        })
    }
```

which returned me the first element no matter what.

this was my second go but here I got an empty array with no elements:

```
getProductName(itemName){
        cy.get("iframe[title='Cart Page']").its('0.contentDocument')
        .should('exist').its('body')
        .should('not.be.undefined').then(cy.wrap)
        .find("div[data-hook='item-list'] section[data-hook='item'] h3[data-hook='product-name']")
        .then(($elem)=>{
            let items = $elem.map((i, el)=>{
                return Cypress.$(el).get("h3[data-hook='product-name']")
            })
            expect(items.get()).to.contain(itemName)
            // expect($elem).to.have.text(itemName)
        })
    }
```

The DOM is quite simple and I am struggling how to do it , if it was java I would put it inside List and iterate through this list but here I truly lose myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the [cypress-iframe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe) package because it's the safest way to ensure the iframe is fully loaded, without clutter in your test.

```js
getProductName(itemName) {

  cy.iframe('[title="Cart Page"]')  
    .contains('h3[data-hook="product-name"]', itemName); // gets just the h3 with text
}
```

Comment: OK, and this is not an assertion it will not assert in my test that the text exist.

Comment: @tupacshakur you are mistaken, [.contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html) will assert that the text exits within an `h3`. You can verify by putting in some non-existing text.